# Preventing an object from being destroyed instantly

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

I am trying to create a single instance of a class object in such a way as to make this instance accessible to any other class that needs it simply by including the header and calling the appropriate form of the `getInstance()` method. I tried to accomplish this by following the Singleton example shown [here](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119) but for some reason, this single instance is destroyed as soon as it is created.

Below is a copy of the header file, `Window.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>

class Window {

public:
    static Window* getInstance();
    static Window* getInstance(const std::string &title, int width, int height);
private:
    Window(const std::string &title, int width, int height);
    ~Window();

    bool init();

    std::string _title;
    int _width = 800;
    int _height = 600;

    SDL_Window *_window = nullptr;

    static Window *_instance;
    // static Window _solidInstance;
};
```

Below is the source file, `Window.cpp`, with some of the irrelevant parts cut out to save space.

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <iostream>

Window* Window::instance = 0;
SDL_Renderer *Window::_renderer = nullptr;

Window::Window(const std::string &title, int width, int height) {
    // Code that isn't relevant to this issue
    std::cout << "Window constructor called\n";
}

Window::~Window() {
    // Code that isn't relevant to this issue
    std::cout << "Window destructor called\n";
}

Window* Window::getInstance() {
    return _instance;
}

Window* Window::getInstance(const std::string &title, int width, int height) {
    if (_instance == 0) {
        std::cout << "Just before construction\n";
        _instance = &Window(title, width, height);
        std::cout << "Just after construction\n";
        // _solidInstance = Window(title, width, height);
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

After building and running this code, the following lines are printed to the console in this order:

```
Just before construction
Window constructor called
Window destructor called
Just after construction
```

This tells me that the instance of Window I created is already destroyed before `getInstance()` even has a chance to return it. I am unsure how to prevent this from happening. I have tried using a regular instance of Window rather than a point to one (see the commented out lines of code referencing `soldInstance`) but this simply gives me linker errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What runs in your main? Anyhow, make your constructor private.

Comment: I am surprised `_instance = &Window(title, width, height);` compiles. Didn't you at least get a warning for that? Turn up warnings if you didn't. This creates a temporary object that lives until the corresponding `}` which is way sooner than you want. Usually you use `static` for that.

Comment: That’s because you didn’t follow the example. What made you decide that the `new` was unnecessary?

Comment: If you didn't know the purpose of new, you should probably look it up. I believe it's important to know what dynamic allocation is (admittedly not as much in c++ as in c) and have at least a little grasp on the lifetime of objects in c++ too I guess, especially when you need to manipulate pointers.

Comment: @nwp no warnings occurred.

Comment: You should change your warning levels [until it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a4ec20d2be1b309).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here: `_instance = &Window(title, width, height);`
You are getting the adress of a temporary window, which gets destroyed after leaving the scope.

Change that to: `_instance = new Window(title, width, height);`

But be sure to delete the window before exiting your program!

An even better solution which would delete the window automatically on exit would be:

```
Window* Window::getInstance(const std::string &title, int width, int height) {
    static Window window{title, width, height};
    return &window;
}
```

Comment: Note that OP has also `Window* Window::getInstance()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
_instance = &Window(title, width, height);
```

This creates a temporary object and takes its address.  As soon as the expression completes, the object is destroyed and you're left with a dangling pointer.

For creating objects that are stored in a more lasting way, use the "new" operator to allocate from the heap:

```
_instance = new Window(title, width, height);
```

Be careful with this singleton approach.  For one, you ask for an instance and provide arguments, which may or may not be used.  If no object has ever been created, you use the provided arguments to create the window.  However, if the window was already created, the provided arguments are ignored and you just get whatever happens to be there.  This will be surprising and infuriating to somebody eventually.  Guaranteed.
Problem two, memory management.  At some point you should delete this pointer.  Perhaps you could save it for program shutdown, by storing it in a unique_ptr, and then you could allocate it with make_unique(), but you should consider the ramifications of whatever choice you make.